# MySQL Function use provided variables throws error

Tags: mysql, create-function

I want to create a function for calculating the distance between points.

The calculation is going as expected, but i receive an error here:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CalculateDistance;

CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDistance(breite double, laenge double) RETURNS INT READS SQL DATA

BEGIN

DECLARE breite DOUBLE;

SET @ibk_laenge = breite;
```

> CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDistance(breite double, laenge double) RETURNS INT READS SQL DATA
>
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE breite DOUBLE
>
> MySQL meldet: Dokumentation
>   1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that >corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter first:

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDistance ...

END //
delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the function definition stops at the first `;` which would make it incomplete.